# Hide columns based on user input

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to setup a plan for 20 employees and 2 years.
I want to hide the weeks that already passed in the input.

Below code seems to work till the "All" part.

With the inputbox I want that the person to enter the value based on the first row, 2023 week 1 (20231) till 2024 week 52 (202452).

If someone enters the value of 202336 it should show 2023 week 36 and later and it hides the previous weeks.

```vb
Sub Hidepastweeks()
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Weeks visible from week:", "Visable weeks")
    Dim c As Range
    
    Range("A2").Value = myValue
    With Range("G1:DF1")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = (myValue <> "All")
        If myValue <> "All" Then
            For Each c In Range("G1:DF1").Cells
                If c.Value < "myValue" Then
                    c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried different sites but they have an equal to formula instead of lesser than.

Comment: What is the purpose for *hiding* the columns? Did you try View > freeze panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hide Columns Before Match (`Application.Match`)

```vb
Sub HidePastWeeks()
    
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Weeks visible from week:", "Visible weeks")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ws.Range("A2").Value = myValue
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("G1:DF1")
    
    ' Allow case-insensitivity with 'vbTextCompare' i.e. 'all = ALL'.
    Dim ItsNotAll As Boolean
    ItsNotAll = StrComp(myValue, "All", vbTextCompare) <> 0
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    ' Show or hide all columns if it's 'All' or not 'All' respectively.
    srg.EntireColumn.Hidden = ItsNotAll
    
    Dim cIndex As Variant ' could be an error value
    
    If ItsNotAll Then
        cIndex = Application.Match(myValue, srg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then ' show
            srg.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count - cIndex + 1) _
                .Offset(, cIndex - 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        'Else ' show none; previously already set
        End If
    'Else ' show all; previously already set
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probbably work as is if you'd take away the quotations around myValue at

> If c.Value < "myValue" Then

Are the weeks written the same as you're requesting from the user input, e.g. 202336 is in CG1 (or whatever)? If not, you'll have to use adjust to be able to compare with the myValue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @notus_Panda, the for column is indeed 202336 so this is all the same. i also tried it without the quotations but that doesn't work as well. Without the quotations all the rows (G till DF) are all hidden.